# Mybatis resultMap match wrong constructor

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I run some test codes like below. but it failed because of Data conversion error.

```java
@MybatisTest
class MemberMapperTest {

    @Autowired
    private MemberMapper sut;

    @Autowired
    private GameAccountMapper gameAccountMapper;

    @Test
    void save_and_find() {
        // given
        Member member = Member.builder()
            .email("user123@example.com")
            .password("password1234")
            .build();

        sut.save(member);

        GameAccount gameAccount = GameAccount.builder()
            .memberId(1L)
            .loginId("user123")
            .nickname("hide on bush")
            .build();

        gameAccountMapper.save(gameAccount);

        // when
        Member findMember = sut.findById(1L).orElseThrow(); // exception!!!!

        // then
        assertThat(findMember).isEqualTo(member);
    }
}
```

### Test Result

- spring boot:3.1.0
- mybatis-spring-boot-starter:3.0.2
- java:17

[image]

### Source code

Member.java

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
public class Member {
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String profileUrl;
    private Boolean deleted;
    private GameAccount gameAccount;

    public Member(Long id, String email, String password, String profileUrl, Boolean deleted) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.profileUrl = profileUrl;
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

GameAccount.java

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@Getter
public class GameAccount {
    private Long id;
    private Long memberId;
    private String nickname;
    private String loginId;
}
```

MemberMapper.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-/mybatis.org/DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="edu.flab.member.repository.MemberMapper">
    <insert id="save" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
        INSERT INTO member (email, password)
        VALUES (#{email}, #{password});
    </insert>


    <resultMap id="memberResultMap" type="edu.flab.member.domain.Member">
        <constructor>
            <idArg column="memberId" javaType="Long"/>
            <arg column="email" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="password" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="profileUrl" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="deleted" javaType="Boolean"/>
        </constructor>
        <association property="gameAccount" javaType="edu.flab.member.domain.GameAccount">
            <id column="gameAccountId" property="id"/>
            <result column="memberId" property="memberId"/>
            <result column="loginId" property="loginId"/>
            <result column="nickname" property="nickname"/>
        </association>
    </resultMap>


    <select id="findById" resultMap="memberResultMap">
        SELECT m.id          AS memberId,
               m.email       AS email,
               m.password    AS password,
               m.profile_url AS profileUrl,
               m.deleted     As deleted,
               g.id          AS gameAccountId,
               g.member_id   AS memberId,
               g.login_id    AS loginId,
               g.nickname    AS nickname

        FROM member m
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN game_account g
                                 ON m.id = g.member_id
        WHERE m.id = #{id}
          AND m.deleted = FALSE
    </select>
</mapper>
```

### Debugging

I expected `Member` class instanced by `Member Constructor`. But, it was skipped. mybatis tried to make it with `GameAccount Constructor`. Thus, `Email` field was matched to `GameAccount Construcor`'s second(=Long type) field.

When I fix it like below, it worked well.

GameAccount.java

```java
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@Getter
public class GameAccount {
    private Long id;
    private Long memberId;
    private String nickname;
    private String loginId;

    public GameAccount(Long id, Long memberId, String nickname, String loginId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.memberId = memberId;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.loginId = loginId;
    }
}
```

MemberMapper.xml

```xml
    <resultMap id="memberResultMap" type="edu.flab.member.domain.Member">
        <constructor>
            <idArg column="memberId" javaType="Long"/>
            <arg column="email" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="password" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="profileUrl" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="deleted" javaType="Boolean"/>
        </constructor>
        <association property="gameAccount" javaType="edu.flab.member.domain.GameAccount">
            <constructor>
                <idArg column="gameAccountId" javaType="Long"/>
                <arg column="memberId" javaType="Long"/>
                <arg column="loginId" javaType="String"/>
                <arg column="nickname" javaType="String"/>
            </constructor>
        </association>
    </resultMap>
```

### Question

Why `Member constructor` was skipped?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'skipped'. MyBatis cannot skip constructor invocation. What happens is that MyBatis instantiates `Member` successfully, but fails to instantiate `GameAccount` because of the incorrect result map definition.